# Network connection failure

Tags: networking, network-manager, interface, ifconfig

There is network connection loss on an Ubuntu 16.04.3 desktop machine.
`systemctl status networking.service` gives following output:

> Failed to start Raise network interfaces.

`sudo service networking restart` command failed too.

`ifconfig -a` gives 3 interfaces as output: `docker0`, `eno1` and `lo`.

There wasn't any configuration change on machine, I tried to restart it too.

I modified `/etc/network/interfaces` file with the following content:

```
auto eno1
iface eno1 inet  dhcp
```

Command `sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart` was successful too, but status is

> active(exited)

Is it possible to restore default network settings?

Comment: You have a [docker bridge](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/custom-docker0/) enabled. Review it.

Comment: @Redbob: I already removed it, but problem still persist.